# Define Color of ObjectStatus Text

Tags: sapui5

I am new to UI5, JS and web developing in general. Following courses on openSAP about SAPUI5, I got this page:

[image: app screenshot]

The city names are displayed in the tags `list/secondStatues/ObjectStatues`.
I would like to turn city's name color into red if it is `"Berlin"`.

Find here the concerned XML View and the controller.js I'm getting an issue from:

#### XML view sample:

```xml
<List>
  <!-- ... -->
  <secondStatus>
    <ObjectStatus
      title="{i18n>statusDeliveryFrom}"
      text="{
        parts: [
          {
            path: 'ToSupplier/Address/City'
          }
        ],
        formatter2: '.formatter.cityColor'
      }"
    />
  </secondStatus>
</List>
```

---

NB: I put `formatter2` because there is another formatter

controller.js sample:

```js
cityColor : function(vText){
  if (vText === "Berlin") {
    return "#FF0000";
  }
},
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to turn city's name color into red if it's `"Berlin"`.

```xml
<ObjectStatus xmlns="sap.m"
   state="{= ${ToSupplier/Address/City} === 'Berlin' ? 'Error' : undefined}"
   text="{ToSupplier/Address/City}"
   inverted="true"
/>
```

The control `sap.m.ObjectStatus` supports various colors via the property `state` which awaits:

#### *Semantic* [Value State](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.ValueState) Colors

- `"Error"` (reddish)
- `"Warning"` (orangish)
- `"Success"` (greenish)
- `"Information"` (blueish / highlighting, since v1.60.1)

#### [*Indication* Colors](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.IndicationColor)

- `"Indication01"` … `"Indication05"` ([Since v1.62](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d01ea07aa8d57842d84d7aaef8ce06168d052cf4))
- `"Indication06"` … `"Indication08"` ([Since v1.75](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/c2f98a4b369f005356ca76d89c80398b48ed827f))

  Here, the colors are still pre-defined by the theme but their *semantic* meanings depend on the application.

  > In contrast to the `ValueState`, the semantic meaning must be defined by the application.

## ➡️ [Samples](https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.ObjectStatus/sample/sap.m.sample.ObjectStatus)

---

In case other colors are required, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42232902/5846045). However, I'd strongly encourage to **avoid custom CSS** if the app is going to be used within an application container such as FLP.